# Customize community login

Tags: community, login

I want to customize the community login page.  Can someone tell me what page/component/aura component that is this portion of the login?

[image: login]

Comment: https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-salesforce-communities-login-and-landing-page-spring-2017/  It's simple you can use the method and code snippet as mentioned in the blog.

Comment: @AbhishekMudireddy indeed, there are two ways, as you suggest via Visualforce, or as I  pointed below using the provided LC template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to enable the loginForm component, which is

[image]

Read the first line of the component, which says

> add implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" to surface the component in community builder

So your second line looks like this

```
<aura:component controller="LightningLoginFormController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
```

From here you can make any customization you need and use this Custom Login Form in your community, just as a custom Lightning Component.

Comment: And actually, you can even go further and migrate this to LWC.